# Update label while a method is running

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

How do I update a label in a aspx page while a method is running? Perhaps using AJAX (update panel)?

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    doThings1();
    label.Text = "Status1";
    doThings2();
    label.Text = "Status2";
    doThings3();
    label.Text = "Done";  
}
```

I want to show step by step. While the method is running when the doThings1() is done, shows "Status1", doThings2() is done, shows "Status2"... In this way, the label doesn't show "Status1" and "Status2", just "Done" when the process is finished. I'd like to show step by step.

Comment: Yeah, or http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/system.web.httpresponse.flush.aspx

Comment: what you are trying ? above code will display `DONE`. you want some kind of progress bar ?

Comment: I think that you should use a client-side perspective. You can accomplish your goal using Javascript and Ajax calls. If this is suitable for you, let me know and I post an example for you.

Comment: what are you trying to do. please elaborate more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule is: 1 request --> one response. 
Different approach:
You can these methods execute with 3 asyncron javascript call and set the labels' text at the success callback.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "URL.asmx/doThings1",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
            // result will be "done" from the function of webservice below.
        // set the first label text
    },
    error: function(xmlHttpRequest, status, err) {
        alert(xmlHttpRequest.statusText + " " + xmlHttpRequest.status + " : " + xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
    }

});
```

Repeat these calls 3 times and do your modifications in different functions.
You can handle your buttonclick at client side with jquery or pure javascript.

You can use a webservice or generic handler to execute server side methods.

[How to create webservice](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/863/Your-first-C-Web-Service)

```
[WebMethod]
    public string doThings1()
    {
        return "done";
    }
```

Comment: the ajax call is only one piece of the puzzle, you also need to have the server side code doing the work and exposing some sort of web service or equivalent that can be polled using ajax.

Comment: I haven't written the full solution, just the direction.

Comment: But you haven't even *described* the remaining work to be done, and you've only shown/discussed a small portion of the larger goal.  I'm not saying you should show the full code for the whole thing, as it would simply be too much, but not even mentioning that there is a *lot* of server side work to be done means that the answer is missing just too much.

Comment: Ok I've posted the instruction at the end.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an easy thing to do, the way it is in a desktop application.  You need to start an asynchronous operation that will continue after the request ends, you'll need to have the client continually poll the server for updates as to the progress, and the server side asynchronous code will need to update some sort of share state (i.e. session, a database, view state, etc.) that the polling method can read the progress from.  All around it's quite inefficient (especially if you have a lot of users doing this) and takes some time to write.  [Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETBackgroundWorker-dda8d7b6/view/SourceCode) is an example on MSDN that does this, to give you an idea of what's involved.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to show the progress of some task that is running on the server.  The [signalr](http://signalr.net/) library will allow you to send real time updates to the client from the server.  So anytime the task completed a stage (Status1, Status2, etc) of the task, it would send an update to the listening clients with the new status.

You could also have some javascript request the task status from the server every few seconds and display it to the user.

Comment: something like this? doThings1(); RegisterStartupScript("", "<script>$('Status1').appendTo("#label");</script>"); doThings2(); etc